# Spark save as CSV dont ignore spaces

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I am trying to save Dataframe as CSV file, I want to retain the spaces. I am using Spark 2.1.1, But when I try to save it as CSV file, all the spaces are trimmed.

I tried these options, but they didn't work.

```
option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace",false")
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "false")
```

Expected CSV format

```
SiteNumber, batch ,DayBatchDate,RecordType   
    190000,    TBD,  12/12/2017,  +00000001
```

My current output:

```
SiteNumber, batch ,DayBatchDate,RecordType   
190000,TBD,12/12/2017,+00000001
```

Answer (score 3):

`ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace` and `ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace` options for the writer have been introduced in Spark 2.2 (
[SPARK-18579](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18579)) so won't have effect in Spark 2.1.